# C# FTP Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type

Tags: c#, ftp

quizá alguien me pueda ayudar con este problema que tengo, intento enviar un archivo (en array de bytes) vía FTP y me muestre el mensaje de excepción "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type." el lenguaje de programación es en C#, Ya busqué en varios foros y aún no he podido encontrar una solución.

este es mi código

```
            try
            {
                var URLFTP = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URLFTP"];
                var PasswordFTP = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PasswordFTP"];
                var UsuarioFTP = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UsuarioFTP"];                    

                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URLFTP + "");// archivo.Nombre);

                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                //request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;  <--- igual probe con ese método

                request.UsePassive = true;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.KeepAlive = false;

                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UsuarioFTP, PasswordFTP);

                byte[] bytes = archivo.binarios;
                request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

                using (Stream request_stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {                        
                    request_stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    request_stream.Close();
                }

                return request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri;
            }               
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.registroLog(3, "error al subir archivo: ", ex.Message);
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Y antes funcionada el método.

Comment: revisa que byte[] bytes = archivo.binarios; este leyendo el archivo, y los demas parametros de entrada esten correctos, URLFTP, etc

Comment: Revise los parámetros de entrada y están correctos porque al aplicar el método:
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dirFtp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                    string res = reader.ReadToEnd();
Me lle correctamente todos los archivos del directorio del servidor.

Comment: Pero al usar el metodo: dirFtp.GetRequestStream() 
Me salta el error mensionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando este metodo que tengo puedo subir archivos mediante ftp a servidores de hostinger, funciona de la siguiente manera.
Lo puedes implementar facilmente.
Primero se le pasa la direccion donde estan los achivos y lo recorre.

```
DirectoryInfo carpeta = new DirectoryInfo(@""+Direccion+"");
                foreach (var item in carpeta.GetFiles())
                {

                    UploadFile(item.Name, "ftp://dir.hostinger.mx", "usuario", "password", item.Name);
                }
```

llama al siguiente metodo que es el que sube los achivos del directoria a la cuenta de FTP.

```
 protected static void UploadFile(string FilePath, string RemotePath, string Login, string Password, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {

            string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath, "*.*");

            foreach (string file in Files)
            {
                using (FileStream fs = File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RemotePath + Path.GetFileName(file));
                    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Login, Password);
                    ftp.KeepAlive = false;
                    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                    ftp.UseBinary = true;
                    ftp.ContentLength = fs.Length;
                    ftp.Proxy = null;
                    byte[] buff = new byte[fs.Length];
                    fs.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                    fs.Close();
                    Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
                    ftpstream.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                    ftpstream.Close();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Cuando utilizo el metodo: 
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile; 
Me salta la exception: "The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command."

Comment: WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails usalo asi

Comment: Cual es la direccion ftp? editala y ponla aqui

Comment: esta es la direccion 

*ftp :// x.x.x.x/Tismart/Recaudacion/*